# Multiple lines with d3.js

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I'm trying to do a multiple lines chart with d3.js, but I don't get it.

This is my console.log(data) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => [{"x":"0","y":"35"},{"x":"1","y":"34"},{"x":"2","y":"36"},{"x":"3","y":"35"},{"x":"4","y":"40"},{"x":"5","y":"35"},{"x":"6","y":"37"},{"x":"7","y":"40"},{"x":"8","y":"45"},{"x":"9","y":"46"},{"x":"10","y":"55"},{"x":"11","y":"63"},{"x":"12","y":"61"},{"x":"13","y":"45"},{"x":"14","y":"48"},{"x":"15","y":"49"},{"x":"16","y":"45"},{"x":"17","y":"44"},{"x":"18","y":"52"},{"x":"19","y":"43"},{"x":"20","y":"37"},{"x":"21","y":"36"},{"x":"22","y":"37"},{"x":"23","y":"34"}]
    [1] => [{"x":"0","y":"10"},{"x":"1","y":"15"},{"x":"2","y":"13"},{"x":"3","y":"15"},{"x":"4","y":"14"},{"x":"5","y":"16"},{"x":"6","y":"17"},{"x":"7","y":"25"},{"x":"8","y":"23"},{"x":"9","y":"24"},{"x":"10","y":"25"},{"x":"11","y":"28"},{"x":"12","y":"27"},{"x":"13","y":"21"},{"x":"14","y":"23"},{"x":"15","y":"19"},{"x":"16","y":"18"},{"x":"17","y":"16"},{"x":"18","y":"15"},{"x":"19","y":"14"},{"x":"20","y":"15"},{"x":"21","y":"16"},{"x":"22","y":"15"},{"x":"23","y":"16"}]
    [2] => [{"x":"0","y":"45"},{"x":"1","y":"49"},{"x":"2","y":"49"},{"x":"3","y":"50"},{"x":"4","y":"54"},{"x":"5","y":"51"},{"x":"6","y":"54"},{"x":"7","y":"65"},{"x":"8","y":"68"},{"x":"9","y":"70"},{"x":"10","y":"80"},{"x":"11","y":"91"},{"x":"12","y":"88"},{"x":"13","y":"66"},{"x":"14","y":"71"},{"x":"15","y":"68"},{"x":"16","y":"63"},{"x":"17","y":"60"},{"x":"18","y":"67"},{"x":"19","y":"57"},{"x":"20","y":"52"},{"x":"21","y":"52"},{"x":"22","y":"52"},{"x":"23","y":"50"}]
    [3] => [{"x":"0","y":"10"},{"x":"1","y":"15"},{"x":"2","y":"12"},{"x":"3","y":"5"},{"x":"4","y":"9"},{"x":"5","y":"15"},{"x":"6","y":"45"},{"x":"7","y":"125"},{"x":"8","y":"345"},{"x":"9","y":"256"},{"x":"10","y":"312"},{"x":"11","y":"345"},{"x":"12","y":"299"},{"x":"13","y":"165"},{"x":"14","y":"354"},{"x":"15","y":"368"},{"x":"16","y":"254"},{"x":"17","y":"213"},{"x":"18","y":"312"},{"x":"19","y":"165"},{"x":"20","y":"54"},{"x":"21","y":"32"},{"x":"22","y":"10"},{"x":"23","y":"5"}]
    [4] => [{"x":"0","y":"2"},{"x":"1","y":"3"},{"x":"2","y":"2"},{"x":"3","y":"1"},{"x":"4","y":"1"},{"x":"5","y":"2"},{"x":"6","y":"3"},{"x":"7","y":"15"},{"x":"8","y":"45"},{"x":"9","y":"27"},{"x":"10","y":"40"},{"x":"11","y":"42"},{"x":"12","y":"35"},{"x":"13","y":"18"},{"x":"14","y":"42"},{"x":"15","y":"40"},{"x":"16","y":"30"},{"x":"17","y":"25"},{"x":"18","y":"40"},{"x":"19","y":"20"},{"x":"20","y":"6"},{"x":"21","y":"4"},{"x":"22","y":"2"},{"x":"23","y":"1"}]
)
```

As you can see, [0] to [4] are 5 different lines,
x being the x-axis for the hours, y being the data.

This is my js in which I insert the drawing code 
(As you can see I get the data from a php document caller dataOutEvo.php)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $.ajax({    
    url: 'dataOutEvo.php',    
    success: function(data) {    

  // -------- HERE -----------

    }

  });


});
```

Actually, should I use d3.js or is it another library which does multiple lines and stacked bars (which I'll later need) and which will use easily my data format?

Comment: What you need for this are [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: Can you help me more ? I tried to understand but I don't get it :/

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar problem a few days ago. Take a look at this JSFiddle and let me know what you think. I tried to annotate it, but I didn't want to spend too much time explaining myself.

http://jsfiddle.net/GV5kK/3/

Here's the key part:

```
//Create our SVG object.
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svgdiv")
    .attr("width", width+70)
    .attr("height", height+70)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 30 + "," + 30 + ")");



//Call the Axis constructors and append them to the SVG object
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xaxis axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxisConstructor);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "yaxis axis")
    .call(yAxisConstructor);

//Join the different arrays in var data to a new set of tags each classed as ".lines".
var topic = svg.selectAll(".lines")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g");

//Go through an array of ".lines" and append the different attributes, including "d" which determines the line's path.
topic.append("path")
    .attr("class", "topicline")
    .attr("d", lineConstructor)
.style("stroke", function(d,i) { return colorscale(i); })
    .style('stroke-width', 3)
    .style('fill-opacity', 0);
```